# How to compare the two tables and get the column name in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like listed below.I need to compare both tables and need to get the unmatched column name is it possible in mysql ?

```
USERS
+----+------------+
| id | login_name |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Chris      |
+----+------------+
| 2  | Cherri     |
+----+------------+


USERS_TEMP
+----+------------+
| id | login_name |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Chris1     |
+----+------------+
| 2  | Cherri     |
+----+------------+
```

So in my case my expected output is want to return the login_name from `USERS_TEMP` table.How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the names that don't match:

```
select u.id, u.login_name, ut.login_name
from users u join
     users_temp ut
     on u.id = ut.id and u.login_name <> ut.login_name;
```

Note:  this only finds users whose ids match, which is consistent with how your question is phrased.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM USERS_TEMP WHERE Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM USERS);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`UNION`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx)

```
SELECT USERS.id, USERS.login_name
FROM USERS
UNION ALL
SELECT USERS_TEMP.id, USERS_TEMP.login_name
FROM USERS_TEMP
```

[Refer this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx)